# Retrieve user agent from device model, os or browser version

Tags: user-agent, wurfl

I have a need to determine the User-Agent given the device model, os or browser versions. Is there any WURFL api which can be readily used for this purpose? Any other library? Please point me to the respective code snippets.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution finally. There getUserAgent method defined in Device interface.

```
        WURFLUtils utils = wurflEngine.getWURFLUtils();
    Set<ModelDevice> mds = utils.getAllModelDevices();
    for (ModelDevice md : mds){
        System.out.println(md.getUserAgent());

    }
```